# How to force use of specific XML parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have Xerces and Oracle XML parsers both in my application's classpath (don't ask why).

When I create a new `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`, the classloader automatically picks up the Oracle XML parser. However, it's not a full/proper implementation, so it's giving me headaches.

Is there a way I can force/tell the classloader to use the Xerces parces when constructing the document builder factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DocumentBuilderFactory` has a [`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) method where you can specify the class name of the implementation you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should've RTFM.

Comment: The inexorable march of time leads to crufty links, alas.  This URL gets to the same JavaDoc for DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance(String, ClassLoader): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29

Answer (score 5):

For my large project, skaffman's answer would have worked MOST of the time, but not ALL of the time because we have multiple sub-projects that depend on these libraries.  We looked at the source to javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(), and found that it uses javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", ...).  This method then looks at a system parameter to determine the correct implementation.

We ultimately fixed it by adding -D parameters to our runtime to force the correct classes:

-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, but our code uses `org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()` to create the sax-parser (which is still buggy in 8u162).

Could fix this using the system property
`-Dorg.xml.sax.driver=org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser`